# Trying to start an Apple Pay session from a document with an different security origin than its top-level frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, subdomain, applepay

Problem:

I have ApplePay on my website (`https://www.example.com/order`), it works and successefull pay.

Now I try to integrate IFrame (`src="https://www.example.com/order"`) in subdomain (`https://sub.example.com`) with form, which contains apple pay and get an error

```
Trying to start an Apple Pay session from a document with an different security origin than its top-level frame
```

Both sites used Https.

Main domain (with and without `www`) and subdomain verified in apple developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Frames with Apple Pay as it is considered bad practice

Comment: Thank you for answer, but It's only bad practice or it's forbidden at all?

Comment: I think it's also forbidden by Apple pay

Answer (score 3):

This error can be found in the webkit [source](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/WebCore/Modules/applepay/PaymentSession.cpp#L69)

```cpp
if (!ancestorDocument->securityOrigin().isSameSchemeHostPort(topOrigin))
    return Exception { InvalidAccessError, "Trying to start an Apple Pay session from a document with an different security origin than its top-level frame." };
}
```

`isSameSchemeHostPort` function [checks](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/WebCore/page/SecurityOriginData.cpp#L137) that the protocol, domain and port of the iframe and page are the same

```cpp
return a.protocol == b.protocol
    && a.host == b.host
    && a.port == b.port
```

**As a result, the protocol, domain, and port of the frame and page must be the same to integrate iframe with ApplePay.**

Comment: Does that mean applePay test projects won't work with Stackblitz. I have deployed my project at https://vbwijnmmw.github.stackblitz.io and I am getting this error. Could you please explain what can I do to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This just got fixed in https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/pull/11485.

Once this fix is in, the `allow` attribute's domain config should be respected - eg. `<iframe src="https://payment.example.org" allow="payment 'self'" />` should work now if the iframe is embedded into parent document hosted on a different domain, eg. `https://host.example.org`.